# Can JsonUtility.FromJson deserialize nested values?

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to deserialize a JSON object with deeply nested values, but all attempts come up empty. Below is a test that fails, but which I expect to pass. Can someone explain what I'm missing?

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using NUnit.Framework;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.TestTools;

[System.Serializable]
class TestJson
{
  public string rootStr;
  public Foo foo;
}

[System.Serializable]
class Foo
{
  public string bar;
}

namespace Tests
{
  public class Serialization
  {
    [Test]
    public void SerializationSimplePasses()
    {
      string json = "{\"foo\":{\"bar\":\"baz\"},\"rootStr\":\"rootStrValue\"}";
      var deserialized = JsonUtility.FromJson<TestJson>(json);
      Assert.AreEqual(deserialized.rootStr, "rootStrValue"); // this works
      Assert.AreEqual(deserialized.foo.bar, "baz"); // this fails
      var reserialized = JsonUtility.ToJson(deserialized);
      Assert.AreEqual(reserialized, json); // this fails
    }

  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first assert for

```
Assert.AreEqual(deserialized.foo.bar, "baz");
```

actually works for me as expected.

---

From the **order** of the fields in your class I would expect the `reserialized` to rather have the value

```
"{\"rootStr\":\"rootStrValue\", \"foo\":{\"bar\":\"baz\"}}";
```

since it goes from top to bottom. This is obviously not exactly equal to the given string `json` though it has basically the same content.

So the

```
Assert.AreEqual(reserialized, json);
```

will always fail as long as your original input `json` doesn't have the exactly matching order of

```
JsonUtility.ToJson(deserialized);
```

---

This is btw also exactly what the output already tells you:

> SerializationSimplePasses (0,027s)
>   ---
>   String lengths are both 46. Strings differ at index 2.
>     Expected: `"{"rootStr":"rootStrValue","foo":{"bar":"baz"}}"`
>     But was:    `"{"foo":{"bar":"baz"},"rootStr":"rootStrValue"}"`
>             -------------^
>   ---
>   at Tests.Serialization.SerializationSimplePasses () [0x0003c] in E:...\Assets\Tests\NewTestScript.cs:**31**